# React - changing background color of a reusable component

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new to React and I'm trying to use a component several times on the page, with a different background color every time I use it. I have tried the code below (which does not change the background color) and couldn't find anything helpful online. Does anyone know how to do this?

The component I am talking about is "Section"

The main page:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <h1 id="mainTitle">My website</h1>
      <h1 id="subTitle">a cool new website</h1>
      <Section style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}/>
      <Section style={{ backgroundColor: "blue"}}/>
    </div>

  );
}
```

The component CSS:

```
.section{
  text-align: left;
  font-size: large;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

The component JS:

```
import './Section.css';

function Section() {
    return (
        <div class="section">
            <p>Text example</p>
            <p>
            <ul>
                <li>item 1</li>
                <li>item 2</li>
            </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Section;
```

Comment: This cannot possibly change the background color each time.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, you don't understand JSX.

**JSX is not HTML**. It means when you write `<something>`, the `Babel` compiler finds if you want to create an HTML element or render a component. This is why all the components need to be capitalized (the compiler needs to find the difference).

### In your case

`<Section>` - your asking to render the component Section **with props** `style` (send the props to the child).

`<div class="section">` - your are asking to render HTML element **with arrtibute** class.

**The solution**: you need to add the `style` to the `div`, like this:

```js
function Section(props) {
  return (
    <div style={props.style} className="section">
      <p>Text example</p>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

A better solution:

```js
function Section(props) {
 return (
   <div {...props} className="section">
     <p>Text example</p>
     <ul>
       <li>item 1</li>
       <li>item 2</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 );
}
```

This way, if you have a very long list of props, you don't need to define all list in the `div`.

The full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-brown-xmtzy?file=/src/Section.js:27-219